# Datanode hbase and namenode are not starting hortonworks

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am getting connection refuse error Even I have right permission my name-node and data-node and they are not starting up. service gives following error :(Connection failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused to 0.0.0.0:50010).

Comment: are you sure that the namenode and datanode services are started?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you didn't config your datanode(maybe your namenode either) or there is something wrong with your configuration file.

As you can see: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml
The default value of dfs.datanode.address is 0.0.0.0:50010.